# Problem with Goo dictionary

Tags: discussion

Whenever I try to go to the [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/) dictionary these days I get the following error:

> お客様のリクエストはNTTドコモのセキュリティポリシーにより拒否されました。
> The Request was rejected by our security policy.

However, if someone links a specific definition of a word from this site, I can follow that link without problem.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Any ideas on how to fix it? Clearing cookies etc. does not work.

I'm running the most up-to-date version of firefox.

Comment: I just tried with Firefox and could access the site without any problems...

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thanks for trying. What country are you in? I'm wondering if it's a consequence of some European data protection rules, or something like that.

Comment: Well, never mind. It's suddenly started working. Not worked for weeks. Definitely didn't work on the day I posted this, but now .... Mysterious.

Comment: OK, glad to hear it's working again for you!